# SASS files compilation from app/src to www/build folder

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, visual-studio-cordova

How do SASS files from src/api folder get copied into www folder in an Ionic 2 projects? Correct me if I am wrong but based on my understanding from

[Ionic v2, How does it work](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/resources/app-scripts/)

"*build : build calls a set of @ionic/app-scripts to compile the Typescript source, compile sass, create a bundle javascript file, etc.*"

its kind of clear how the process compiles the .ts files into the www folder and creates a bundle file but for sass files this is not that clear:

"*sass : sass walks the application’s directory tree to find scss files and assemble them into one css file.*"

When it says application's directory, does it mean the src/app directory or the www/build directory? Which task[script] is responsible for compiling these src/app folder into the www folder? Where is the configuration file in regards to this?

Comment: just digging through some of the files in the @ionic folder (rc6) I have found that the build.js file tends to do alot of this, particularly the buildUpdateTasks() and buildUpdate() functions, utlizing webpack I assume. /node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/bin/build.js You can go down the rabbit hole if you wish with minify.js and sass.js etc. they're all utilizing one another. Im pretty sure it also takes anything from the /src folder as the theminig scss is included at the root

Answer (score 0):

The Ionic build process is done using https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts. One part of the build is SASS compilation. You can find its configuration here: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts/blob/master/config/sass.config.js.

The default configuration says "to search for sass files in the same directory as the component module".

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged **visual-studio-cordova**, I am assuming you are using **Visual Studio**. All you have to do is open up your **Task Runner Explorer** and choose the **package.json**. It should have a **build** command there. Right-click it and choose **Run**. The process should transpile sass file.